# Why SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: No route to host (65) when trying to send email with PhpMailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am attempting to use PhpMailer to send an email of an MP3 to a user. When I try to send an email to the user I get a message saying:  SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: No route to host (65) . I have read this might be the result of gmail not agreeing with a different server but I don't see any remedy. I switched from tls to ssl and that didn't help. I also tried 3 different physical locations and the problem still persists. This worked fine initially and maybe something switched off but I don't know what. UPDATE I am having this problem only on my hosted site . localhost is working now. Is there some necessary configuration on my shared server I am missing? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
session_start();
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$m = new PHPMailer(true);


try{
$m->SMTPDebug = 2;
$m->isSMTP();
$m->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$m->SMTPAuth = true;


$m->Username = 'munsonatl@gmail.com';
$m->Password = 'somethingsecret';


$m->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$m->Port = 465;

$m->setFrom('munsonatl@gmail.com', 'Mailer');
$m->addAddress('munsonatl@gmail.com', 'Matt Macy');
$m->addReplyto('reply@mattmacy.com', 'replyAddress');


require 'connect.php';

$itemNum = $_SESSION['itemNum'];


$query2 = "SELECT* FROM MP3s_For_Sale WHERE itemNum = :itemNum";
$LastProduct = $db->prepare($query2);
$LastProduct->bindvalue(':itemNum', $itemNum);
$LastProduct->execute();

$rows = $LastProduct->fetch();

$filename = $rows['path'];
$filesize = $rows['filesize'];
$string =  $rows['wholeMP3'];
$encoding = 'base64';
$type = $rows['type']; 

$m->AddStringAttachment($string,$filename,$encoding,$type);

$m->isHTML(true);

$m->Subject = "Here is an Email";
$m->Body = "<p>This is the body of the email</p><br><strong>Test for 
HTML formatting</strong><br>";
$m->AltBody = "This is the body of an email";
$m->send();
echo "message has been sent";

unset($_SESSION['itemNum']);

} catch (Exception $e){
echo "message could not be sent", $m->ErrorInfo;
}

?>
```

Comment: Well, there is nothing we can help from a programming point of view. You are facing a network or configuration issue.

Comment: This is a common problem which must have a resolution. I have a functioning internet connection so the problem must lye somewhere.

Comment: Is that your real email and password?  Might want to head over to gmail and change it, quick!

Comment: Certainly there is a problem somewhere. I did not deny that. But this is a place offering help with _programming related issues_. This is not a general help forum or something.

Comment: Dude, https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49037947/revisions go change it, now!

Comment: are you using a server hosted on something like goDaddy?

Comment: If you know where the problem is please tell me so I can research further. As for the moment the issue appears to be with PhpMailer. I am using web.com.

Comment: Yes, it's a common problem - with your network, meaning PHP (and probably everything else too) cannot open a connection to gmail. Read the troubleshooting guide and the advice you're being given instead of dismissing it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have read the troubleshooting guide and don't see any fix. I still don't know what exactly is at fault.

Comment: Rather than be told we can't help you it would be helpful to know anything about the problem. I have tried to connect from 3 different locations so the problem must be somewhere between the network and my code. Please if you know anything specific please inform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking with my hosting company for the third time they said web.com does not require the use of ports or even SMTP to work with PhpMailer. I commented out everything that has to do with Ports or SMTP and as a result it now works kind of. I haven't been able to send email to my secondary email account at all and it works only most of the time with my gmail account. If someone can tell me anything else about web.com and what is going on it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the reputation to leave a comment like the others did, but I have had this issue before caused by the port being blocked on shared hosting. If you need to check if yours is blocked, then look at [PHP Checking if a port is Active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36759307/php-checking-if-a-port-is-active)

Comment: I will continue to read through that post. I don't understand exactly how to test for an open port. even if this tells me whether closed or not I still don't know how to fix it. I appreciate the direction.